# Word Count & Read Time Errors I Can't Track Down And Fix In Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Using Wordpress, I altered a custom theme to display the post word count and estimated reading time with a script a found from a website. I even added an option to turn it on/off. The script works fine..., or so I thought.

When I turned on the Wordpress debug options on to look for errors in the theme, I get one for this script. However, I don't see the problem.

**The errors displayed when webpage is viewed**:

> This post contains
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: post in
>   /home/xxxxxx/wordpress.xxxxxx.com/wp-content/themes/xxxxxx/functions.php
>   on line 1676
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /home/xxxxxx/wordpress.xxxxxx.com/wp-content/themes/xxxxxx/functions.php
>   on line 1676
>
> 52 words.
>
> This post will take you about
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: post in
>   /home/xxxxxx/wordpress.xxxxxx.com/wp-content/themes/xxxxxx/functions.php
>   on line 1683
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /home/xxxxxx/wordpress.xxxxxx.com/wp-content/themes/xxxxxx/functions.php
>   on line 1683
>
> 1 minute to read.

**The script I copied and added to the: /functions.php**

```
/*** ADD POST WORD COUNT ***/
function word_count() {
    $content = get_post_field( 'post_content', $post->ID );
    $word_count = str_word_count( strip_tags( $content ) );
    return $word_count;
}

/*** ADD ESTIMATED READING TIME ***/
function reading_time() {
    $content = get_post_field( 'post_content', $post->ID );
    $word_count = str_word_count( strip_tags( $content ) );
    $readingtime = ceil($word_count / 200);
    if ($readingtime == 1) {
      $timer = " minute";
    } else {
      $timer = " minutes";
    }
    $totalreadingtime = $readingtime . $timer;
    return $totalreadingtime;
}
```

**Options I added in the: /functions.php**

```
    /* MAIN SETTINGS - Show Entry Word Count Setting */
    $wp_customize->add_setting('swag_main_post_word_count', array(
        'default' => 'swag-main-post-word-count-yes'
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control('swag_main_post_word_count', array(
        'label' => 'Display Post Word Count',
        'section' => 'swag_main_design',
        'type' => 'select',
        'choices' => array(
            'swag-main-post-word-count-yes' => __('Yes'),
            'swag-main-post-word-count-no' => __('No')
        )
    ));

    /* MAIN SETTINGS - Show Entry Reading Time Setting */
    $wp_customize->add_setting('swag_main_post_read_time', array(
        'default' => 'swag-main-post-read-time-yes'
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control('swag_main_post_read_time', array(
        'label' => 'Display Post Read Time',
        'section' => 'swag_main_design',
        'type' => 'select',
        'choices' => array(
            'swag-main-post-read-time-yes' => __('Yes'),
            'swag-main-post-read-time-no' => __('No')
        )
    ));
```

**In the theme template file: /template-parts/content.php**

```
<?php
    if (isset($swag_main_post_word_count) && $swag_main_post_word_count=='swag-main-post-word-count-yes') {
            echo '<div class="word-count">This post contains ';
            echo '' . word_count() . '';
            echo ' words.</div>';
    }
?>

<?php
    if (isset($swag_main_post_read_time) && $swag_main_post_read_time=='swag-main-post-read-time-yes') {
            echo '<div id="reading-time">This post will take you about ';
            echo '' . reading_time() . '';
            echo ' to read.</div>';
    }
?>
```

I don't think the fault is with the options I added, but I added it here just in case. I think the fault is in the script I copied itself. What is it and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/*** ADD POST WORD COUNT ***/
function word_count() {
    global $post;
    $content = get_post_field( 'post_content', $post->ID );
    $word_count = str_word_count( strip_tags( $content ) );
    return $word_count;
}

/*** ADD ESTIMATED READING TIME ***/
function reading_time() {
    global $post;
    $content = get_post_field( 'post_content', $post->ID );
    $word_count = str_word_count( strip_tags( $content ) );
    $readingtime = ceil($word_count / 200);
    if ($readingtime == 1) {
      $timer = " minute";
    } else {
      $timer = " minutes";
    }
    $totalreadingtime = $readingtime . $timer;
    return $totalreadingtime;
}
```

I've added `global $post;` to each function so it is in scope when `$post->ID` is called.